# Define $f:(0,1) \to R$ by $f(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}-\sqrt\frac{x+1}{x}$ Can one define $f(0)$ to make $f$ continuous at 0?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multivariable-calculus

Define $f:(0,1) \to R$ by $f(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}-\sqrt\frac{x+1}{x}$
Can one define $f(0)$ to make $f$ continuous at 0?

So from my understanding, $f$ is continuous if $Lim_{x\to \infty}f(x)=f(0)$ Is this the correct? If the limit exists at 0, does that mean that it is continuous at 0?

Comment: I'm guessing it's just a typo, but just in case, you want $\lim_{x \to 0^+} f(x) = f(0)$, not $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = f(0)$. Note the $+$, since $f$ is only defined to the right of $0$. If the limit exists, then you can set $f(0)$ to be this number, to get a continuous function. So, you're right: the limit just has to exist.

Answer (score 0):

$f(x)=\frac{1-\sqrt{x+1}}{\sqrt{x}}=\frac{1-(x+1)}{\sqrt{x}(1+\sqrt{x+1})}=\frac{-\sqrt{x}}{1+\sqrt{x+1}}$

Therefore $f(x)$ is continuous at $x=0$.

Comment: $f$ is not continuous at $0$ but can be continuously extended to $x=0^+$.

Comment: @trancelocation Whether or no it is continuous at $x=0$ requires it to defined.  My answer was an attempt to give it a definition.  In the original form it was undefined $\infty -\infty$ or $\frac{0}{0}$ at $x=0$.

Comment: herb steinberg: Whatever you bring up as justification, the sentence "Hence $f(x)$ is continuous at $x=0$." is a wrong statement.

Comment: @trancelocation  Are you concerned that for $x\lt 0$, $f(x)$ is imaginary?  I don't understand what your concern is.

Comment: herb steinberg: If you do not understand why then sentence "Hence $f(x)$ is continuous at $x=0.$" is a wrong statement, I strongly recommend that you revise the difference between the existence of a limit of a function at a point vs. its continuity at this point.

Comment: @ trancelocation Using $f(x)=\frac{-\sqrt{x}}{1+\sqrt{x+1}}$, then $f(0)=0$ and $f(x)\to 0$ as $x\to 0$.  I guess you don't approve of the simplification.

Comment: herb steinberg: Are you aware that, for example, $f(x)=\frac xx$ and $g(x)=1$ are not the same functions? According to your reasoning the would be the same. But $g$ is a continuous extension of $f$ from $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ which is possible, since the $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac xx = 1$.

Comment: I am quite aware of the point you are trying to make.  What it boils down to is that $f(x)$ in its original form is undefined at $x=0$, therefore I can choose to define $f(x)$ to be the limiting value.